# How to move my stats to a self-hosted website?

Tags: statistics

How do I move my stats from my old WordPress.com blog to my new WordPress.org self-hosted website? I've enabled Jetpack and moved my subscribers only.

I would really like to keep my precious stats.

Comment: I believe stats is specific to the domain name of the blog.

Comment: General instructions for moving from WordPress.com blog to a self-hosted blog using the WordPress.org software: http://en.support.wordpress.com/moving-a-blog/#moving-to-wordpress-org